# Listview not loading on first attempt

Tags: java, android

I am getting one weird problem.I have a List view with multiple column I am
Populating that listview using the data which i have stored in the array list the problem is On button click i am not able to populate the List view its only showing me the header with no data in rows and columns but when i go back and again click on the button i am able to load the data i dont know what exactly  is the  issue I am facing any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.I am posting my list view code

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylistData;

     ArrayList<String> pv= new ArrayList<String>();

     String response;

     @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.listmain);


            pv = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("Array_list");

            System.out.println("ARRAYLIST---->"+pv);


            final ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

         mylistData =  new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         list.addHeaderView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header, null, false));


        String[] columnTags = new String[] {"Center", "Locality", 

"Address","District","Phone","Email"};


        int[] columnIds = new int[] {R.id.col1, R.id.col2, R.id.col3, R.id.col4,

R.id.col5, R.id.col6};

        int k=0;

        for(int i=0; i<=100; i++)

        {

            HashMap<String,String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

         //initialize row data

         for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)

         {
             if(k<=pv.size()-1)

             {

            map.put(columnTags[j],pv.get(k));

           k++;

             }

            }

        mylistData.add(map);

        }
SimpleAdapter arrayAdapter = new SimpleAdapter

(this, mylistData, R.layout.rowmain,columnTags ,columnIds);

list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

}

}
```